# how to reinitialise DataTable in AJAX response

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

Here I am filtering the data of table based on status by clicking buttons using ajax, the functionalities are working well but I can not reinitialise the DataTable.
Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Completed').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      method: "post",
      url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>manager_CompletedIncidents",
      dataType: "json",
     success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
          $('#table_id').dataTable({
              destroy: true,
          });
       $('#IncidentDetails').html(response);
       $('#table_id').dataTable();
     }
    });
  })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destroy first using

```
$('#table_id').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

Then reinitailize

```
$('#table_id').dataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in one liner

```
$('#table_id').DataTable().draw();
```